# Se cierra la sesión de dos páginas iguales que corren por distintos puertos

Tags: nodejs, sailsjs, pm2

Tengo dos proyectos iguales corriendo por distintos puertos con `pm2` usando distintas bases de datos (mongodb). Abro cada una en una pestaña del navegador y como tienen un sistema de login, al cerrar la sesión de una, se cierra la sesión en la otra, también si en una inicio sesión y en la otra simplemente recargo la pagina en la parte de login, en la que había iniciado sesión se cierra automáticamente la sesión. ¿Esto podría ser algo del servidor, de los navegadores o es lógica de programación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las cookies no diferencian por puerto.

Una solución rápida y práctica es hospedar los sitios en diferentes subdominios, cosa que las cookies sí respetan.

Comment: alguna liga donde pueda leer mas acerca de esto?

Comment: En el [RFC 6265](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265), que establece el funcionamiento de las cookies. Hacé CTRL + F: "ports".